# Algolia Magento2 force reindex products

Tags: magento2, algolia

I'm using Magento 2.1.7 and Algolia Magento 2 extension 1.6.0

We update stock and price of all products in the night directly.

How can I force re-index all my products to Algolia?

Also, how can I force re-index single product to Algolia?

Comment: why not a cronjob that calls an extesion after the update?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a full reindex with command:

```
$ php bin/magento indexer:reindex algolia_products
```

To force a reindex of a single product, just save the product in Magento administration. It'll get reindexed.

Comment: For single product re-index, I need command or programmatic way. I cant manually save a product every time.
Also, product may get updated with direct query and Magento events are not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below to re-index a single product to Algolia.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productId = 100;
$indexerRegistry = $objectManager->get("Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry");
$indexer = $indexerRegistry->get('algolia_products');
if (!$indexer->isScheduled()) {
     $indexer->reindexRow($productId);
}
```